# Convert a query from spark.sql to impala

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, impala

I have the below query in pyspark:

```
spark.sql= ("select id, track_id, data_source
             from db.races 
             where  dt_date = 20201010") 
             .groupBy("id", "track_id", "data_source")
             .agg(cnt('*').alias("num_races")) 
             .withColumn('last_num_id', col('id').substr(-1,1)) 
             .withColumn('last_num_track_id', col('track_id').substr(-1,1)) 
             .withColumn("status_date", lit(previous_date))
```

And I want to convert it to impala query .

My attempt until now:

```
select id, track_id, data_source
from db.races
group by  id, track_id, data_source
...
```

I can understand until the part of `groupBy` but after that I can not understand exactly how these pyspark functions can be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with Impala, but here's my attempt at writing an SQL query:

```
select
    t.*,
    substr(t.id, -1, 1) as last_num_id,
    substr(t.track_id, -1, 1) as last_num_track_id,
    '(put the previous_date here)' as status_date
from (
    select id, track_id, data_source, count(*) as num_races
    from db.races 
    where dt_date = 20201010
    group by id, track_id, data_source
) as t
```

Comment: I think that .withColumn() creates a column with name id from the last digit of last_num_id. In the query that you have provided you only rename it. Am I right?

Comment: @Thkas I think it creates a column with name last_num_id from the last digit of id?

Comment: Oh yes, it was my misunderstood. Thank you very much.